# Curl and grep html text

Tags: grep, regular-expression, curl, html

Is there a way to grep html text from a curl request and output grab the value that is between two html tags?

More specifically the input value of a form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read content out of html downloaded via `curl`, using a mixture of the regular UNIX commands (so `grep`, `awk`, etc.)  Exactly how depends on exactly what the form looks like and how you want to interpret it.

You can also do it with `perl` and other languages which have libraries which make it easier.

However, input forms only have content in the fields when some person or process fills it in *locally* before submitting it via a POST (or less likely a GET) request.

Input forms can have default values obviously, but it seems what you're asking is if you can somehow pull the data out of a form that's been filled in, the answer is not from curl, because curl asks the web server for the web page and you get an empty form.

Maybe you could clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Good enough. I'll try a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is

- [pup for html](https://github.com/ericchiang/pup)
- [xpup for xhtml/xml](https://github.com/ericchiang/xpup) (using xpath rather than css selectors)

They are inspired by the [json parser jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq)  and offer similar syntax and behavior:

```
curl -s https://news.ycombinator.com/ | pup 'table table tr:nth-last-of-type(n+2) td.title a attr{href}'
```