# How to pipe html into lynx?

Tags: pipe, curl, html, stdin, lynx

I am testing some ajax call from the console. I like get rid of the meta-information noise that is html markup and just read the content, hence I like to pipe it into a terminal browser, e.g. lynx.

Yet:

```
curl www.google.de | lynx
```

just opens a new instance of lynx.

I don't want to:

```
curl www.google.de > someFile.html && lynx someFile.html
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
curl www.google.de | lynx -stdin
```

as `man lynx` shows:

> -stdin read the startfile from standard input (UNIX only).

As an alternative you could also ditch lynx and use pup HTML parser instead, [as pointed out here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271984/12471)