# How to pipe html into w3m?

Tags: curl, w3m

In [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/271945) is shown how to pipe `curl` output to `lynx`. How can get the same with `w3m`?

I mean something like:

```
curl https://www.google.it | w3m
```

I do not want to use a temporary file.

Comment: I haven't tried it to be sure, but the manual lists `w3m -T text/html`

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`w3m` is a pager. So to force HTML interpretation of text on stdin, you need to ask for it explicitly:

```
curl https://www.google.it | w3m -T text/html
```

Comment: You can also add the `-dump` flag to skip the pager and send the output to stdout or pipe it to something else.